Table of contents not showing when \section is renewed
I am very new to LaTeX so forgive me if my question is not clear enough. I am trying to renew the \section command. I want to add space before and after each section and I want to change the font. I have many sections, so I believe it is easier this way, than to format each section separately. This works fine, but when I am trying to insert a table of contents the code won't compile. I am not sure why, any help is much appreciated. Below is a sample code.
\documentclass[12pt, twoside]{article} 

\let\oldsection\section
\renewcommand{\section}[1]{%
  \vspace*{50pt} % Space before the section title
  \oldsection{\Huge \textbf{#1}} % Custom section style in the document
  \vspace{25pt} % Space after the section title
}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{Intro}

\end{document} 


welcome! the original \section in turn uses a command which is responsible for writing the line to the table of contents, generating text for headers/footers, setting bookmarks (if hyperref is loaded) etc. it also determines whether this section should be numbered (which affects whether the section ends up in the toc etc., too). in general, redefining commands without checking their definitions is a high-risk strategy :-).

How or where is \oldsection defined?

do you have something like \let\oldsection\section in your real document?

do not redefine \section  in that way you should never put font changes in the section (or old section) argument, you do not want \Huge fonts in the page head or table of contents. you can specify the fonts used for section headings without  such a definition either directly by copying the definition from article.cls or using packages such as secsty that offer specific declaratiions for section fonts and spacing

Yes, I added the oldsection part, forgot to copy it, sorry about that. So I understand that I should not redefine the \section command. Is there another way I can add automatically add before and after each section the spaces and the text formatting which I was trying to do? Sure, I could copy the commands for each section, but I thought it would be more elegant to do it once and then automatically it would update all sections

yes. it isn't that you can't redefine it. you just need to do it properly.

but it is sectsty, I think? (@DavidCarlisle)

Give \usepackage{sectsty} \sectionfont{\Huge} a try.

Thank you for all your answers! It helped me a lot to familiarize myself with LaTeX!

As David said, either copy the definition from article.cls and modify it or use a package such as sectsty which does the same thing but provides a more user-friendly interface.
Here's a modified version of a definition I use:
\documentclass[12pt, twoside]{article}
\makeatletter
\def\section{\@startsection{section}{1}%
  \z@{50pt \@plus\fill\pagebreak[3]}{25pt}%
{\normalfont\Huge\bfseries}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{Intro}

\end{document}

This discourages page breaks right after section titles and encourages them before. It also makes the space before extensible, so TeX can stretch it to make a good page break when necessary.

Use a dedicated package such as titlesec.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\titleformat{\section}[block]
 {\Huge\bfseries}
 {\thesection}
 {1em}
 {}

\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{50pt}{25pt}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\clearpage

\lipsum[1][1-4]

\section{First section}

\lipsum[2][1-4]

\section{Second section}

\lipsum[3][1-4]

\end{document}


The [block] argument tells LaTeX this is a standard sectional title; the next argument sets the overall font; the next argument is the for section number (maybe adorned, if you want a period use \thesection., for instance); the next argument is the spacing between number and title; the last argument can be empty and in this case it means “typeset the title”.
For \titlespacing, the * means that the next paragraph indentation is killed; the first argument is the space on the left (so 0pt means “flush left”); the next is the space before and finally you set the space below.

your comment disappeared before I could thank you.

@cfr You fixed the code too early! ;-)
